# Reading in a text file to an array including spaces

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I have to read this text file which already exists. This code compiles and works but it only reads in one word per line.

For example: my txt file looks like this:

- word1 word2 word3 word4
- word5 word6 word7
- word8 word9

But it outputs on the screen:

- word1
- word2
- word3.. etc.

How can I get it to read the txt file into the array including the spaces?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    string friendConnections[9];
    string line;
    int loop = 0;

    ifstream networkFile("network.txt");

    if (networkFile.is_open())
    {
        while (!networkFile.eof())
        {
            istream& getline (networkFile >> line);
            friendConnections[loop] = line;
            cout << friendConnections[loop] << endl;
            loop++;
        }
        networkFile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Can't open file" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout << friendConnections[loop] << endl;` makes it new line

Comment: What happens if you do `cout << line` instead of `cout<<friendConnections[loop]<<endl` ?

Comment: btw what is `istream& getline (networkFile >> line);` supposed to mean? As I understand it creates a reference with the name `getline` that is never used and initializes it with `networkFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `while(std::getline(networkFile,line))` instead of `while(networkFile.eof())` and `istream& getline (networkFile >> line);`

`istream operator>>` goes until the whitespace which isn't what you want.

Comment: @userboss22 Y U NO ACCEPT ANSWER?